# xcode 6 object library is empty (no matches)

Tags: iphone, xcode, object

I am trying to follow instruction to create "Hello World" but I don't seem to have anything in my object library?  It just says "No Matches" in the dialog.  what am i missing here?
Thank you.

Comment: How does your problem occur? What do you want to do? We can't do anything with that description...

Comment: I have new installation of Xcode 6.  1. create New Project iOS->Single View Application     when I click on object library (circle with square inside), it just says "No Matches"  and nothing is shown.     I am trying to follow instruction for "Hello World" tutorial and it says to go to object library to create edit box.   Surely I am missing something.

Comment: what object library!?

Comment: I've been seeing this today as well. The Object Library in Interface Builder of Xcode 6.1. That is normally where you find UIButton, UILabel, etc. The area is void of objects and instead says "No Matches". Nothing is in the search field, so it shouldn't be filtering the list. I've restarted Xcode and even restarted my computer. :-/

Answer (score 33):

I discovered a solution. It was happening when I was editing a Storyboard in an Assistant Editor. I closed the Assistant Editor and opened the Storyboard in the main editor and my Object Library began working again. I would guess this is a bug in Xcode.

Comment: anyone seeing this please raise a bug with Apple ;-)

Answer (score 15):

I have got the same problem today, started a new project, opened main.storyboard, object library was saying "No Matches".
solution: right click on main.storyboard file, select "open as", choose "interface builder-storyboard" and now the objects library should be filled.

Comment: this above solution worked for me on Xcode 8.1 version

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem, I tried opening another file and switching back to storyboard again started showing everything normal.

Answer (score 0):

My object library tab was totally empty, not even the filter field existed. My solution was the following: at the right upper corner, I found a symbol circle with square inside. Clicked there and the options appear, among them "Label" which was what I was looking for.